# Parsear Date a String

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans-8.2, parsear

Estoy haciendo una base de datos en sql server conectado a java (NetBeans)
Tengo una tabla en SQL Server donde tambien tengo un campo con un tipo de dato **Date**
Les anexo mi codigo de la tabla en SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE ALBUMES (
ID_Album INT    NOT NULL identity (1,1),
Nombre VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,
Artista INT  NOT NULL,
Fecha_Lanzamiento Date NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT UQ_Nombre UNIQUE(Nombre),
CONSTRAINT FK_Artista FOREIGN KEY (Artista) REFERENCES ARTISTA(ID_Artista),
CONSTRAINT PK_ID_Album PRIMARY KEY( ID_Album ));
```

Pero no se como parsear ese tipo de dato a string para ingresarlo desde NetBeans y que se guarde en mi BD
Les adjunto mi codigo en Java

```
private void btn_ingresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        //paso 1 cargar el driver
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        //paso 2 coneccion con la BD
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://EDDATZIN:1422;databaseName=BDALLMUSIC";
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "eddatzin", "eddatzin");

        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("insert into ALBUMES values(?,?,?,?)");

        pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txt_ID.getText().trim()));
        pst.setString(2, txt_nombre.getText().trim());
        pst.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(txt_artista.getText().trim()));
        pst.setDate(4,formate txt_fecha_lanzamiento.getText());

        pst.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Exitoso");

    } catch (Exception er) {
        System.out.println("Error" + er);
    }


}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Para tomar una cadena ingresada por el usuario y convertirla a una representación de fecha en java, para ello puedes valerte de `SimpleDateFormat`, que se usa así:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;  

    String sFecha = "07/05/2019";  
    Date fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(sFecha);
```

Luego, puedes usar esa variable para llamar a `setDate`:

```
   pst.setDate(4, fecha);
```